# Javascript adjusting a field with form level script

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

I am attempting to get a field "ADJUST.0" to change the value of another field, "AATVelocity.0" when the value is anything except 1. I am doing this inside the form JavaScript. It is running but......

Debugger tells me the following:

1:AcroForm:AATAverageVelocity.2:Calculate
ReferenceError: GetField is not defined
1:Document-Level:adjust

Here is my code thusfar:

```
var v = GetField("AATVelocity.0").value;

if ( GetField("ADJUST.0").value !==0 ) {
event.value = ( GetField("ADJUST.0").value * v );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is case sensitive. See below.

```
var v = this.getField("AATVelocity.0").value;

if ( this.getField("ADJUST.0").value !==0 ) {
    event.value = ( this.getField("ADJUST.0").value * v );
}
```